# Google cloud storage favicon for PDF File

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, favicon

I have some pdf files hosted on Google Cloud Storage.
These files are public and I open them using their public link.

Is there a way I can customize the favicon shown by the browser when I view those PDF?

Can I put a custom Favicon for my bucket?

See screenshot to see which icon I mean, is the Icon shown in the browser Tab, this is chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in my research of the [question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156044/google-cloud-storage-favicon-for-pdf-file) I found this. Given that I will share the same answer, so the community here can check it.

Currently this is not possible.  When this kind of features are not available, the best is to open a Feature Request -FR- in the Public Issue Tracker of GCP. [This is a FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/169787367) about your request.

I would recommend you to [‘star’](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) it to ensure that you receive updates about it. You can also [adjust notification](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/set-notification-preferences) settings by clicking the gear icon in the top right corner and selecting settings.

The more stars in the issue, the most probability to be implemented the feature request. Also, adding this kind of needs makes the GCP Eng team to have a better visibility of the real/currently needs of the users.